# How to print Exception in Json format

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Graph api java code

```
 _appClient.users(sFrom)
    .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
        .newBuilder()
        .withMessage(message)
        .withSaveToSentItems(null)
        .build())
    .buildRequest()
    .post();
```

when I try to hit method I am getting below error..

> com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: ErrorAccessDenied
> Error message: Access to OData is disabled.
>
> POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{some](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bsome) email ID name}/microsoft.graph.sendMail
> SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.49.0
> [...]
>
> 403 : Forbidden
> [...]
>
> [Some information was truncated for brevity, enable debug logging for more details]

I need it in JSON format , How can I get that, and also I need to get requestid in response..

for example like below

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token is empty.","innerError":{"date":"2023-11-09T08:58:24","request-id":"cbe585bc-d83b-4611-9df8-f1e3ad9b74de","client-request-id":"cbe585bc-d83b-4611-9df8-f1e3ad9b74de"}}}
```

I need RequestID in error response and the exception need to in JOSN format.

Comment: What http client do you use? Most likely you can set the log level on the http client to log the traffic. Just like ktor or okhttp. But for the error it means that you need to authenticate beforehand or check the credentials for the authentication.

Comment: OkHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(authProvider).newBuilder()

Comment: How can get request-id in response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to handle the exceptions and format the responses accordingly.
Something along these lines should work

```java
try {
    _appClient.users(sFrom)
        .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
            .newBuilder()
            .withMessage(message)
            .withSaveToSentItems(null)
            .build())
        .buildRequest()
        .post();
} catch (GraphServiceException ex) {
    // Handle the GraphServiceException
    String errorResponse = ex.getMessage(); // Get the error response as string
    String requestId = null;

    // Try to parse request ID from the error message
    int startIndex = errorResponse.indexOf("request-id");
    if (startIndex != -1) {
        int endIndex = errorResponse.indexOf(",", startIndex);
        if (endIndex != -1) {
            requestId = errorResponse.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
        }
    }

    // Process the error response and request ID as needed
    System.out.println("Error Response: " + errorResponse);
    System.out.println("Request ID: " + requestId);
}
```

Comment: Tried above code to set up but I am getting compeltime errors

Comment: getting error at below lines   ------------------------------------------------------------ String errorResponse = ex.getResponseBodyAsString(); // Get the error response as JSON
         String requestId = ex.getResponseHeaders().get("request-id"); // Get the request-id

Comment: import statement is :- import com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException;                      The method getResponseBodyAsString() is undefined for the type GraphServiceException

Comment: @ManiBellamkonda made slight tweaks to the erroring line Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Thank you @user3402754, it is working , I made little change as per my code. it is working for me.. Thanks a  lot  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll know that the **exception** class has several important fields that helps you find the error.
for example:

1-you can create your custom exception class with below fields:

```
    class MyCustomException{
        public String exceptionMessage;
        public String className; 
        public MyCustomException(String exceptionMessage, String className) {
            this.exceptionMessage = exceptionMessage;
            this.className = className;
        }   
    }
```

2-get exception fields that you need(in this example, className and exceptionMessage):

```
     try {
           ;//your code    
    } catch (Exception e) {
          MyCustomException exception=new MyCustomException(e.getMessage(),e.getClass().getName());
          String json= new Gson().toJson(exception);    
    }
```

now, json is your JSON format.